# Web-to-lead Page is Not Accepting Chinese Characters and Not Creating Leads

Tags: web2lead

The web-to-lead form is not creating any leads if we submit Chinese characters in the form fields.

Can someone let me know how to submit Chinese language in a web-to-lead form?

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the problem characters?

Comment: Have you tried debugging using hidden fields? To test the Web-to-Lead form, add the line <input type="hidden" name="debug" value="1"> to your code. This line redirects you to a debugging page when you submit the form. Remove this line before releasing the Web-to-Lead page to your website. For more details : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm

Comment: Hi Daniel, chinese characters like 您好, if i enter these characters in the web to lead form and submit, the lead is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

hie,
the Language that you choose while setting up the W2L is will be for the form labels.  If users want to see the form labels in their language and if you have setup form labels in user's langauge, please select the appropriate language while setting up W2L.  As far as I know you don't need to do anything regarding data entered in different langauge at the website end. Let us know if you run into any issue.

Comment: HI Paarth, if i enter chinese chars in the fields, and submit the form, the leads are not getting created, and this is not about the chinese labels of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the web 2 lead form it will have two commented out form fields:

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="yourEmailAddressHere@YourDomain.com">                                    -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
```

Try uncommenting these two hidden inputs. Then when you submit the form Salesforce will relay back what you submitted.

Do your sample Chinese characters of 您好 work in the UTF-8 charset?

I tried manually POSTing to Web2Lead using Postman in Chrome:

[image: Web 2 Lead Request]

[image: Web 2 Lead Response]

So there is no immediate indication that Salesforce is having issues with the character encoding.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried it with uncommenting the hidden input fields and submitted the form with chinese characters and the form is submitted, but the leads were not created in the leads object in salesforce. if i enter other than chinese characters and submitted the form then the leads are getting created. i am very novice to salesforce environment, so no idea why leads are not getting created with chinese characters or how to debug the issue./